# FileReference.load() not populating FileReference.data

Tags: apache-flex, filereference

I am trying to use the load method of FileReference object to load the data and use it to display a thumbnail of the selected image.

However, after calling `fr.load()`, `fr.data` remains `null`.

I'm using Flex Builder 3.0.2 on Windows 7 with Flex SDK 3.4 and Flash Player 10 Debug. If I evaluate `fr.load()` in Eclipse's watch variables list, I get an error reading `"No such variable: load."`

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you import flash.net.FileReference

Comment: +1 for I learned something from this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you waiting for the `load()` to complete?  Try adding an EventListener to listen for the load to be finished.

[FileReference docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html#load())

```
fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
                                        handleLoad(e);
                                    });
```

The `handleLoad` function that you write can then get at the data via `e.target.data`

Comment: This was the problem, thanks. I'd known earlier that I should wait for the event, but forgotten. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is applicable only to FP9.

---

Are you sure you are using the right class? `FileReference` does not have a *load* method or a *data* property. I guess you are referring to the `URLLoader` class - it does have both and that's what you should be using to load data. [FileReference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) class is for downloading files from the server to the user's machine (not to the SWF) and uploading files from user's machine to the server.

Use [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class for loading data to the SWF and [Loader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Loader.html) class to load other SWFs and images to your SWF. `Loader` class has a `content` property analogous to the `data` property of `URLLoader` that will hold the loaded content. The `load()` methods of both these classes are asynchronous (returns without waiting for the load to be completed) and hence, as @dustmachine noted, you can access the loaded data/content only after the `Event.COMPLETE` is fired.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(theURL));

private function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  var urlLoader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
  trace(urlLoader.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but with ActionScript 3 and Flash Player 10, FileReference does have a load() method (which loads the content of the file into a ByteArray) and a data property (which contains the aforementioned ByteArray). I had to upgrade and reconfigure Flex Builder to get it to see these things, though.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me - haven't done FP 10 specific stuff yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with FileReference class and load() function. The problem can solved in this way:

1. Open the "Flex Build Path" tab.
2. Expand "Flex 3", select "playerglobal.swc" and click "Remove".
3. Note the directory path in "Flex 3 - " (on my system it's /Applications/Adobe Flex Builder 3 Plug-in/sdks/3.2.0).
4. Click "Add SWC" and navigate to the that path, and then deeper into frameworks/libs/player/10, select playerglobal.swc.
5. Expand "playerglobal.swc", double-click "Link Type" and change it to "External".
6. Open the "Flex Compiler" tab
7. In "HTML wrapper", change the "Require Flash Player version" to 10.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass anything to the fileReference.

e.g from a datagrid

```
var listFiles:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
var _refUploadFile:FileReference = new FileReference();                 
_refUploadFile = listFiles.selectedItem.file;   

_refUploadFile.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do the following first:

```
fileReference.cancel();
```